# Problems with recursive function in OCaml

Tags: function, recursion, integer, ocaml

i am doing a function in OCaml with i want to count the number of iterations in the variable n. This is the function:

```
let mapdoble f1 f2 l = 
let rec aux n f_1 f_2 l1 l2= match(n,f_1,f_2,l1,l2) with
    (n,_,_,[],l2) -> l2
    | (n,f_1,_,h::t,l2) when n mod 2 = 0 -> aux n+1 f1 f2 t l2@[f_1 h]
    | (n,_,f_2,h::t,l2) when n mod 2 = 1 -> aux n+1 f1 f2 t l2@[f_2 h]
in
    aux 0 f1 f2 l [];;
```

When i compile it i have this error, i don't know what it is:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'b -> 'c list -> 'd -> 'd but an expression was expected of type int
```

Comment: I think you're simply missing parentheses around the two instances of `n+1`.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends is write, you have to put parenthesis around `n+1`. You also have to match all cases, the compiler should warn you about that too with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function application, that is just written as a juxtaposition of function name and its arguments, binds tighter than infix operators, i.e., it has a higher precedence. To clarify the above said, let's go to an example. The expression:

```
aux n+1 f1 f2 t l2@[f_1 h]
```

is actually parsed by a compiler as:

```
(aux n) + (1 f1 f2 t l2) @ ([f_1 h])
```

now, I hope, it is obvious, why you got so strange compiler messages. In particular, you are trying to apply `(+)` operator to the result of `aux n`, which is actually a function of four arguments and definitely not an int.

So the correct version would be:

```
aux (n + 1) f1 f2 t (l2 @ [f_1 h])
```

You have also some issues with pattern matching, it is not irrefutable, but it is out of the scope of the question.